# Regular Expression Robot Framework

Tags: python, regex, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I used Replace String Using Regexp Function in Robot Framework to replace "\|" to "###PIPE###" but It is not working.

```
*** Test Cases ***
TestCast1
${result}   Replace String Using Regexp   Bell|fieldName|11|LastName\|dd    \\\|    \#\#\#PIPE\#\#\#
```

result

```
Bell###PIPIE###fieldName###PIPIE###11###PIPIE###LastName###PIPE###dd
```

My Expected result

```
Bell|fieldName|11|LastName###PIPE###dd
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: can you post a proper input string?

Comment: Input String = Bell|fieldName|11|LastName\|dd   Isn't it proper ?

Comment: what is your regexp function?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to replace a fixed string. Use the normal [`Replace String`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Replace%20String) to replace fixed strings.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `re.sub()` function(in case if the last "*piped*" part of the input string could be dynamic):

```
input_str = 'Bell|fieldName|11|LastName\|dd'
result = re.sub(r'\\\|(\w+)$', r'###PIPE###\1', input_str)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
Bell|fieldName|11|LastName###PIPE###dd
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a rough idea, it is ugly but it works.. :)

```
${result}   Replace String Using Regexp   Bell|fieldName|11|LastName\|dd    \\|dd    \#\#\#PIPE\#\#\#dd
Log To Console  \n\n${result}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while working on a nestable For Loop for Robot Framework. Here's my theory of what's happening, sans actually having your keyword's code:

Event 1: You send the inputs `Bell|fieldName|11|LastName\|dd`, `\\\|`, and `\#\#\#PIPE\#\#\#` to `Replace String Using Regexp`. That's what you typed.

Event 2: `Replace String Using Regexp` receives `Bell|fieldName|11|LastName|dd`, `\|`, and `###PIPE###`. This happens automatically.

Event 3: I'm assuming that some code in your keyword puts `\|` into another keyword that does the actual replacing. When that happens, `\|` turns into `|`. Then, when that keyword does the replacing of the text, it finds four instances of `|` and replaces them all with `###PIPE###`.

FIX

Event 1: Send the inputs `Bell|fieldName|11|LastName\\|dd`, `\\\\|`, and `\#\#\#PIPE\#\#\#` to `Replace String Using Regexp`.

Event 2: `Replace String Using Regexp` receives `Bell|fieldName|11|LastName\|dd`, `\\|`, and `###PIPE###`.

Event 3: `\\|` turns into `\|`. Then, when the other keyword does the replacing of the text, it finds one instance of `\|` and replaces it with `###PIPE###`.

Based on what I can see in your code, `|` doesn't need a literal, so the only things that do are the `\`s and `#`s. So, what you sent is basically the same as `Bell|fieldName|11|LastName|dd`, `|`, and `\#\#\#PIPE\#\#\#`